# como enviar parâmetros no d3.json para php

Tags: d3.js

boas existe alguma forma de mandar parâmetros no d3 para fazer um pedido ao php.

tenho um form de pesquisa que vai enviar dados para o php em forma de post queria eu e devolver o resultado em json

```
d3.json("../querys/querys.php", function(error, graph) {
```

Answer (score 1):

A [documentação do D3](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json) refere só dois argumentos passados à função:

```
d3.json(url[, callback])
```

isso quer dizer que tens de enviar os dados numa *query string* concatenada com a url, e o servidor tem de interpretar isso.

```
var data = '?nome=joao&idade=45';
d3.json("../querys/querys.php" + data, function(error, graph) {
```

Comment: Olá Primo :) neste caso se ele tem que fazer POST, não pode ser com o querystring no URL, os dados num HTTP POST são enviados no body, não no URL. e neste caso, usando o D3, existe o xhr.post.

exemplo:
`d3.xhr('../querys/querys.php').post(JSON.stringify({a: 2, b: 3}),       function(error, data) {
      // callback
    });`

Comment: @andre.barata bom ver-te por aqui :) Não tinha lido que o pedido era POST... Dá uma resposta, assim a pergunta fica melhor respondida :)

Comment: e do lado o php nao consigo ler os valores ..

Comment: @user2964140 como estás a receber esses valores no PHP?

Comment: como post . usei o exemplo dado pelo andre barata

Comment: @user2964140 não tinha lido que precisavas enviar via post. Deixo um exemplo para GET, como tinha referido na resposta: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/pxdvn83p/

Comment: estou a tentar fazer um diagrama de sankey origem destino